# Conditional: If all numbers in array are divisors without remainder

Tags: javascript

My problem states:

> Print all numbers from low to high.
>   If any number being printed is divisible by any divisor number in arr, print the number + the word ¨one_match¨ 
>   If the number being printed is divisible by ALL the numbers in the array, it should output the number + “all_match”.

In the function below, I seem to be able to produce conditions for one of the numbers in the array (by iterating through the array) and the base case (none are evenly divisible).  I'm seeking help with the middle  case (if all are divisible), it seems the inside loop is not appropriate for this... an additional `for...in` doesn't really jibe with arrays... any ideas to complete the function? (Or optimize it entirely)

```
function check(arr, low, high) { 
  for (var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
      if (i % arr[j] === 0)
        console.log(i + ' one_match')
        //  trouble here ->   else if (i % arr[j] && ???)
      else
        console.log(i);
  }
};

check([2,3],1,7);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just count the matches and see what you have after the inner loop:

```js
function check(arr, low, high) { 
  for (var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (i % arr[j] === 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count === arr.length) {
      console.log(i + ' all_match');
    } else if (count > 0) {
      console.log(i + ' one_match');
    } else {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
};

check([2,3],1,7);
```

#### A more condensed variant

```js
function check(arr, low, high) { 
  for (var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    var count = arr.filter( d => !(i % d) ).length;
    console.log(i + (count === arr.length ? ' all_match'
                   : count > 0 ? ' one_match'
                   : ''));
  }
};

check([2,3],1,7);
```

Comment: I like it.  I'm wondering if anything comes in that is able to check the condition directly at once...

Comment: Obv. you're highly decorated, and very well could be the most optimal...    ; )

Comment: I added a more condensed variant.

Comment: Any reason for strict equality? .length and count are both int no?

Comment: No reason really, would indeed be nicer to use `===` though, as in general `==` can be source of hard-to-spot errors. I would suggest to always use `===` unless it really needs to a *coercion* style of comparison. Good remark.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(arr, low, high) { 
  for (var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    var any = false, all = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
      any = any || (i % arr[j] === 0);
      all = all && (i % arr[j] === 0);
    }
    console.log(i+(all?' all_match':(any?' one_match':'')));
  }
};

check([2,3],1,7);
```

Its a classic case of OR vs AND condition.

Comment: Good approach. Better to use logical operators instead of bit operators though.

Comment: `any = any | (i % arr[j] === 0);
      all = all & (i % arr[j] === 0);`
can you explain this syntax? 
you set any equals any or i mod arr[j]... ?

Comment: ok that's a bit operator... always had trouble understanding their use case and implementation

Comment: i see part of it... shifting the bit on the boolean... but the expression directly after that in an assignment is new for me

Comment: Changed the boolean operator to logical for performance and to avoid confusion about any bit shifting. I was just doing a simple boolean OR, AND test.